# Memory Traces from Intel Vtune

Tags: intel, intel-vtune

Is it possible to extraction memory traces information along instruction count from intel vtune? If yes, can you please give me idea how to perform this operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to get PEBS information from Precise Event with iPTU, which runs on top  of the VTune driver. As far as I know, iPTU support was discontinued on IvyBridge+, but you can still collect the trace on SandyBridge-.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/use-intelr-performance-tuning-utility-to-view-result-from-vtunetm-performance-analyzer

I don't exactly remember how to do that, but there are command line report tools to output memory ref. report.